# Copy and convert dir structure to unique filenames

Tags: bash

I'm trying to copy all the *.jpg files in a directory structure to another dir, using the file struture as the pattern for the new files names.

Example input:

```
./in/file1.jpg
./in/file2.jpg
./in/cat1/file1.jpg
./in/cat1/file2.jpg
./in/cat1/file3.jpg
./in/cat2/file1.jpg
./in/cat2/file2.jpg
./in/cat2/file3.jpg
./in/cat2/sub/file1.jpg
./in/cat2/sub/file2.jpg
./in/cat2/sub/file3.jpg
```

Example output:

```
./out/file1.jpg
./out/file2.jpg
./out/cat1-file1.jpg
./out/cat1-file2.jpg
./out/cat1-file3.jpg
./out/cat2-file1.jpg
./out/cat2-file2.jpg
./out/cat2-file3.jpg
./out/cat2-sub-file1.jpg
./out/cat2-sub-file2.jpg
./out/cat2-sub-file3.jpg
```

So far I've tried using find, but the closer I got was preserving the directory structure with --parents

```
$ find ./in -name '*.jpg' -exec cp --parents -t ./out '{}' '+'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p out
cd in/

while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   file="${file#./}"
   echo cp "$file" ../out/"${file//\//-}"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Once satisfied with the output, you can remove `echo` before `cp` command.

Comment: The variables at second line from the end are reversed, I've changed it to this `cp "$file" ../out/"${file//\//-}"` Appart from that, your solution is perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this quite easily. The setup:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch 1.jpg 2.jpg
$ mkdir -p foo/bar baz
$ touch foo/1.jpg foo/bar/1.jpg baz/1.jpg
```

Enable the magic:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
```

Replace slashes with dashes in paths:

```
$ for file in **/*/*.jpg; do echo "${file}" "${file//\//-}"; done
baz/1.jpg baz-1.jpg
foo/1.jpg foo-1.jpg
foo/bar/1.jpg foo-bar-1.jpg
```

Now replace `echo` with `mv` to apply the magic.